# Wyvern and CKEditor - tags within custom styles not working

Tags: css, wysiwyg, wyvern, ckeditor

I've got a Wyvern field using Typekit, custom CSS and JS. I have a style called 'callout-right' that is applied to divs. It looks like this:

[image: callout right]

The problem: when I try to change text within the styled div, Wyvern applies the div style to h2, h3, etc.
[image: Problem]

Here's the HTML it generates. You can see Wyvern is applying the callout-right class to my h2 tag.
[image: Source]

I want it to leave my text elements alone.

My JS file is:

```
CKEDITOR.addStylesSet('wyvern', [
{name:'Image on Left',element:'img',attributes:{'class': 'left'}},
{name:'Image on Right',element:'img',attributes:{'class': 'right'}},
{name:'Callout Right',element:'div',attributes:{'class': 'callout-right'}},
{name:'Callout Left',element:'div',attributes:{'class': 'callout-left'}},
]);
```

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a Wyvern thing at all, its CKeditor's behavior. Wyvern just wraps CKeditor and provides a few EE specific features. Any and all behavior inside of the editing region is all CKeditor's behavior. You'll have better luck at the CKeditor forums for something like this.

Comment: Scoured the web - no luck. Anyone?

Comment: Noted on CKEDitor forums, no response. http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor-3.x/addStylesSet-class-applying-all-styles

Comment: I think this is a limitation of CKEditor.